# salesforce:security token reset after refreshing the sandbox

Tags: salesforce, sandbox

I recently, refreshed my sandbox. and logged out. The next time I tried to log in, it did not let me log in. Also, there was an email notification for new security token (which was neither requested nor the password was changed). How can this be? And how can I start logging in again. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing your sandbox will effectively create a new Salesforce org with a new unique OrgId.

Part of this process modifies all the user names that were copied form production to be unique as well. As these are all new users they get new security tokens to be distinct from the production users. The password immediately after refresh will be the same as production.

See Knowledge Article: [Sandbox login and password](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005238&language=en_US)